# Creating a User Login System: Put logic in Code or Database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am trying to create a login system thats generic so that it can be adapted for use in various apps. I decided that 2 main "parts" of the system will be User Meta Data & Roles/Resources/ACL.

**1. Metadata**

I thought of keeping most data like what meta data are available for users in the database, so that admins can manage them using some GUI.

Problem is how can I then configue how I want inputs to render (textbox, checkbox, radios etc.). Then another problem is validation, filters.

**2. ACL**

I think for simple ACL it will work fine. But suppose I want say users to be able to modify posts they own. In `Zend_ACL` that is accomplished with Assertions. I thought that will make a "simple" login system overlly complex? Also it will be hard to build I suppose?

---

Currently I have my database like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Logging in users:** I recommend using a separate controller (call it `Auth` for instance) that has `loginAction` and `logoutAction`. `Zend_Auth` ([Zend_Auth using database](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.html)) will check the database for the right credentials. Once the user is verified, you will save it in the global accessible place(the `Zend_Auth` class has methods to do this). This is also a good moment to query which roles the user has and store them.

**Metadata part of your application:** I'm not sure what the question is exactly but I assume you want to store dynamic information about user and have a GUI for admins to manage this. Why you would render different types of controls? Validating the information can be done by defining a lot of the most common metadata (like Twitter) and create rules for them. In the `save` action for the metadata you would validate using these rules.

**ACL:** Resources rarely change, you are better off putting them in a configuration file (for speed). You should give a lot thought to resources: what are they exactly to you? Controllers? Modules? Create a plugin that will `preDispatch` every request checking the role of the logged in user against the requested resource. E.g.:

```
$action = $request->getActionName();
$controller = $request->getControllerName();

// role, resource, privilage
if (!$acl->isAllowed($user->role, $controller, $action) {
    //go to access denied page!
}
```

Now that Zend_ACL is used for the global access rules, you are better off checking for specific access inside the action itself (like `if ($loggedInUser == $article->author) {//edit the article};`).

Also don't forget Zend_ACL can be integrated with Zend_Navigation to hide menu items users are not allowed to use (and more).

Comment: Hmm ... for the meta part perhaps you misunderstood me? maybe I dont get ur answer. By usermeta I mean things like twitter/facebook name, blog url, etc. They dont really relate to ACL or hide/show controls depending on role. All users will have the same meta data fieds. Of course with different values.

Comment: Yes I guess I did misunderstand that part. I will adjust my answer.